# multiple countdown timers in uitableview

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, nstimer

I'm developing a native application clone of Snapchat or Facebook Poke.
I have a few issues related to timers and tap&hold functionality in received messages.

I have a `viewcontroller` (`ViewControllerIncomingMessage`) with a `tableview` which shows received messages and a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` that opens a detail view (starts `timer` and update a `countdown` label. When the long press gesture ends I dismiss the view and schedule every second the following timer:

```
- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

This actually works but prevents rows from being deleted (because of reloadData of table)

Anyone has already implemented a functionality like that? 
Please could you give me any hint about implementing timer update in the best way.

Comment: So the issue is that the user cannot delete rows from the table because you are reloading it every second? Why are you reloading every second?

Comment: @Wain I think the OP is reloading every second in order to update a label that counts down ("5 secs", "4 secs"…)

Comment: @AaronBrager, I thought that was part of the detail view. It seems like there are 2 different timers at work here...

Comment: @AaronBrager You're right

Comment: my answer is more general eventually: where to handle timers?

Comment: @madcowzz Instead of reloading the whole table with a timer, consider using KVO to bind the UILabels on your table cell to a "time remaining" property in your data model.  Have your timer update the data model; the UILabels will be notified of the change through KVO and update appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for your fast replies! I'been very busy in this period. KVO should be a great way to update table (I've never used it before!!). Anyway I've a still have a question: reloading entire table allowed me  to handle data model's update easier than in timer's callback.

Comment: My implementation is very similar to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918472/multiple-countdown-timers-inside-uitableview)